# WinDgb: "Unable to get thread times - dumps may not have time information"

Tags: windbg

I created process memory dump using x64 task manager.  For some reason when I execute !runway in debugger I get the following error: !runaway: extension exception 0x80004002.
    "Unable to get thread times - dumps may not have time information"

The OS I'm running Windows 2008 R2 x64

Thank you for any assistance in this issue.

Comment: Did you try to look into it on your own?

Comment: It works on Win7 x64 for a 64 bit application dump, tried WinDbg 6.12 64 bit and 6.2 32 bit. Flags of my dump are 0x1826. Can you run `.shell -ci ".dumpdebug" find "Flags"`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you created a dump for a 32-bit process on a 64-bit OS. You need to use a special debugger extension to look at the 32-bit process as if you were using a 32-bit debugger. Enter the following command to load the debugger extension:

```
!load wow64exts
```

Enter the following command to tell the debugger extension to switch to x86 (32-bit) mode:

```
!sw
```

Now you should be set.

Comment: steve, I am also facing this issue, and when I enter !sw, getting this error - "The current thread doesn't have an x86 context."

Comment: This can happen if you don't have the required symbol files. You can force the reload of a pdb with .reload /f <name> /i